# JNIEnv->GetMethodID for createRealMatrix(double [][] data) in org/apache/commons/math3/linear/MatrixUtils

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

This is a snippet of what I have:

```
...
jclass jrmc = jenv->FindClass("org/apache/commons/math3/linear/MatrixUtils");
jmethodID jmid = jenv->GetMethodID(jrmc, "createRealMatrix",
    "([[D)Lorg/apache/commons/math3/linear/RealMatrix;");
....
```

Based on my understanding from [org.apache.commons.math3.linear.MatrixUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/src-html/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/MatrixUtils.html#line.127) and [JNI Type Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html) this seems like it should find the method. Obviously I am missing something.

Why is the code above not working? Note jrmc is not 0 it is the call to `GetMethodID` that is causing the issue (`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is a static method. You need to use [`GetStaticMethodID()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetStaticMethodID) instead.